# Download dropbox images to Netlify build folder

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm trying to retrieve images from my dropbox folder into my Jekyll build on Netlify, but the images are unreadable with the following code. I think that I'm using the wrong conversion for the contents.

```
dbx
  .filesListFolder({ path: "/images" })
  .then(response => {
    response.entries.forEach(entry => {
      const { name, path_lower } = entry;

      if (entry[".tag"] === "file") {
        dbx
          .filesDownload({ path: path_lower })
          .then(data => {
            const filename = path.resolve(IMAGES_DIR, name);
            const filecontents = data.fileBinary.toString("base64");

            fs.outputFile(filename, filecontents).catch(error => {
              if (error) {
                return console.log("Error: file failed to write", name, error);
              }
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: file failed to download", name, error);
          });
      }
    });
  })
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Download-dropbox-images-to-Netlify-build-folder/m-p/367384#M20791 ]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing

```
const filecontents = data.fileBinary.toString("base64");
```

to

```
const filecontents = data.fileBinary;
```